# Visual Studio 2010: suddently Locals, Immediate Window and Watches don't work

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2010, immediate-window

I have this problem that a week ago, when debugging, suddently the "Locals" window is blank, the "Immediate Window" and Watches don't work and all return "Unable to evaluate the expression."

Also the standard debugger display stopped giving me any info when I break the execution to check out stuff :-(

[image]

I have played around with all the debugger settings, but none of them seems to have any effect what so ever on my problem.

I did install the MVC3 RC1 and the Nupack just before my problem started, but removing them haven't solved anything. 
I also removed all extensions and addons one by one to find the cause, but no result..

Does anybody have an idea?

I'm running on Win7 x64 on a Standard Core2 based laptop.

Comment: I hate to ask this, but given that you installed some RC stuff and then uninstalled it, have you uninstalled and reinstalled VS? I would try that first.

Comment: Switch back to the Debug configuration.

Comment: Don't use a debugger. A debugger is the mother of all evil: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/602138/is-a-debugger-the-mother-of-all-evil

Comment: Try `devenv /setup` or `devenv /resetsettings` (which will, uh, reset your settings, so be sure to save them first (Tools » Import and Export Settings...) if you care about them).

Comment: MY current install is a clean RTM install. 
- I have tried to reinstall but still no luck.
- Debug/Release/x86/AnyCPU - no difference.
- Resetting VS setting didn't work either ... Man!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently this problem arises when both MVC 3 RC and .NET Framework Async CTP are installed on the same machine.

You need to uninstall MVC 3 RC but since it also comes with ASP.NET Web Pages, NuGet and a Visual Studio update those have to be removed along with it.

You can automate the process by opening a Visual Studio command prompt with Administrator privilege and running all of the following commands in it:

wmic product where name="Microsoft ASP.NET MVC 3 - Visual Studio 2010 Tools" call uninstall

wmic product where name="Microsoft ASP.NET MVC 3 - VWD Express 2010 Tools" call uninstall

wmic product where name="Microsoft ASP.NET Web Pages" call uninstall

wmic product where name="Microsoft ASP.NET Web Pages - Visual Studio 2010 Tools" call uninstall

wmic product where name="Microsoft ASP.NET Web Pages - VWD Express 2010 Tools" call uninstall

wmic product where name="NuGet" call uninstall

msiexec /package {BC0464FA-A0BA-3E38-85BF-DC5B3A401F48} /uninstall {3069D446-63C5-38F4-9D28-41858024419C}

msiexec /package {85076DFF-7A17-3566-9CC0-488E6E6D4494} /uninstall {3069D446-63C5-38F4-9D28-41858024419C}

If the problem still persists however uninstall .NET Framework Async CTP as well.

After uninstalling both frameworks and reinstalling MVC 3 RC1 everything is now like before on my machine. However you can choose to install either the Async CTP or ASP.NET MVC 3 RC1 and it will work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Do you also have the Async CTP installed?

Take a look at this: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/11/11/a-few-quick-asp-net-mvc-3-installation-notes.aspx#async