# Install Async CTP Problem

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to use the Async CTP, while it appears to install correctly neither of the updates (.NET Framework Async CTP, Microsoft Visual Studio Async CTP) appear in Programs and Features.  When trying to run any of the samples the async and await keywords generate errors:

The type or namespace name 'async' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

The type or namespace name 'await' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I'm running version 10.0.30139.1RTMRel of Visual Studio.

Anyone seen this before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This post solved my problem:

[Visual Studio 2010: suddently Locals, Immediate Window and Watches don't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4189736/visual-studio-2010-suddently-locals-immediate-window-and-watches-dont-work)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this problem arises when both MVC 3 RC and .NET Framework Async CTP are installed on the same machine.

You need to uninstall MVC 3 RC but since it also comes with ASP.NET Web Pages, NuGet and a Visual Studio update those have to be removed along with it.

To proceed open a Visual Studio command prompt* with Administrator privilege and run all of the following commands:

wmic product where name="Microsoft ASP.NET MVC 3 - Visual Studio 2010 Tools" call uninstall

wmic product where name="Microsoft ASP.NET MVC 3 - VWD Express 2010 Tools" call uninstall

wmic product where name="Microsoft ASP.NET Web Pages" call uninstall

wmic product where name="Microsoft ASP.NET Web Pages - Visual Studio 2010 Tools" call uninstall

wmic product where name="Microsoft ASP.NET Web Pages - VWD Express 2010 Tools" call uninstall

wmic product where name="NuGet" call uninstall

msiexec /package {BC0464FA-A0BA-3E38-85BF-DC5B3A401F48} /uninstall {3069D446-63C5-38F4-9D28-41858024419C}

msiexec /package {85076DFF-7A17-3566-9CC0-488E6E6D4494} /uninstall {3069D446-63C5-38F4-9D28-41858024419C}

If the problem still persists however uninstall .NET Framework Async CTP as well.